# Symfony2 Could not load type EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem when I'm trying to create an EntityType field in my Symfony2 form type.

This is the piece of code from the official EntityType reference in Symfony2 manual:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType; 

...

$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
        'choice_label' => 'username',
    ));
```

Going back to the browser I'm getting the `Could not load type "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType"` error.

The EntityType class exist in the given namespespace.

Do I need to get some aditional extensions for this field type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What version of Symfony are you using?

This `FooBarType::class` thing is new in Symfony 2.8 and 3.x, older versions do not support it. Try replacing `EntityType::class` by `'entity'` and see if that works. When you upgrade to Symfony 2.8 you may use the FQCN and from 3.x this will be the only option.

Comment: Haven't noticed that it's a new feature. My Symfony2 version is 2.7.6. Replacing EntityType::class with 'entity' solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Need to w8 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 8):

The EntityType class is not located in the common Type classes folder (`Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\`), but in `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\`

So if you are using Symfony 3 or Symfony 2.8 and the `EntityType::class` syntax, you must put

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
```

Comment: Solved my problem. I guess I wasn't looking closely enough at the namespaces.